# Short story: Space war, group developing new techs defeated by enemies using older technologies

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm 90% sure the name is "**Technology**" I believe it from the 70's not sure though.  It was a space war scenario where a ruling group started just developing new techs but problems kept slowing them down that their enemies using older technologies defeated them, and had a humorous twist at the end. Help been looking for a while.

Comment: Sounds like "Superiority" by Arthur C. Clarke.

Comment: Clarke's "Superiority" (from 1951) has been reprinted [a whole bunch of times](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40897) and has its own [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superiority_(short_story)).

Comment: See also [this old Q & A](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/857/process-management-and-high-technology-weapon-novel-name-and-author) and [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142157/intergalactic-war-weapons-designs-flaws).

Comment: Can you include the "humorous twist"?

Comment: You can read it online [here](http://www.mayofamily.com/RLM/txt_Clarke_Superiority.html). Is that the one you're looking for?

Comment: That was it!!!!!!   Thanks for your help you've saved what was left of my sanity